# ¿Qué debo hacer para poder crear subcarpetas y ejecutar los seeders correctamente?

Tags: laravel, seeders

Estoy creando bastantes seeders y me interesa ordenarlos por carpetas, pero al hacer esto y ejecutarlos no me deja porque al parecer si no están directamente en la carpeta database/seeders sino en una subcarpeta no los encuentra.
A la vez estoy creando un seeder que ejecuta un grupo en particular, esto ya lo logro hacer.

Un ejemplo de lo que trato de hacer es esto:

database/seeders/

seeders_1/

```
    Seeder_1Seed.php 
    Seeder_2Seed.php 
    Seeder_3Seed.php  -> Este seeder ejecuta el 1 y el 2
```

seeders_2/

```
    Seeder_4Seed.php
    Seeder_5Seed.php
    Seeder_6Seed.php -> Este seeder ejecuta el 4 y el 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Laravel asume que ejecutas el `seeder` desde la clase Database\Seeders\DatabaseSeeder (Archivo usado por defecto).

Para poder ejecutar otros seeder que estén en sub carpetas tienes que especificar la ruta completa del archivo.

```
php artisan db:seed --class="Database\\Seeders\\seeders_1\\Seeder_3Seed"
```

Edición: Como comentaste también es necesario agregar el nombre de la subcarpeta al namespace, de otra forma no va a reconocer el archivo. Normalmente las diagonales invertidas son el caracter de escape en un string por lo que en el ejemplo puse doble diagonal invertida, en algunas ocasiones los IDE aceptan una sola diagonal invertida.

Comment: Gracias, para complementar lo que dices me toco añadir el nombre de la subcarpeta en el namespace, es decir:

namespace Database\Seeders\seeders_1;

Y para ejecutarlo en mi caso que uso VSCode en Windows no me sirvió como dijiste pero si me sirvió con un solo slash, así:

php artisan db:seed --class="Database\Seeders\seeders_1\Seeder_3Seed"

Comment: Ah, cierto, gracias, agregué tu comentario en la edición de la respuesta

Comment: @DiegoRamos, si te fue útil la respuesta no olvides marcarla como aceptada, de esta forma ayudamos a otros usuarios a ver que la pregunta tiene solución y así podemos mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que aún no han sido resueltas.